# Какой цвет у ссылки

Tags: bootstrap, color

Подскажите плз. какой цвет у ссылки когда на нее наведен курсор? Тоесть `hover`. Искал но везде написано как изменить default стиль, а мне нужно изменять на default color когда навожу курсор на кнопку.

В проекте используется *bootstrap*.

Comment: a:hover{ color: #цвет;} - оно?

Comment: да, но какой цвет?

Comment: вам нужен номер цвета который сейчас?

Comment: на который изменяется цвет ссылки когда на нее наведен курсор.

Comment: открываете dev tools браузера (chrome - F12), в вкладке Elements выбираете ссылку, пкм->:hover и смотрите вкладку Styles. Там будут все стили ссылки при наведении, в том числе и color

Comment: смотрел там нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51706/discussion-between-nueq-and-javavladuxa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заглянул в bootstrap css и цвет указан там.
**bootstrap.min.css**

```
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus,a:hover {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline
}

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px
}
```